# SSO troubleshots

Tags: single-sign-on

I set up SSO on production org and when I try to login I catch - xxxx.my.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/saml/SamlError

What I already check

1. There are no records about login attempts in Login History
2. FederationId is correct and I use it when login
3. SSO enabled + case-insensitive
4. Certificates is up-to-date
5. It works on dev but the same configuration doesn't work on prod
6. On the IDP side we have actual SAML configuration
7. Add Assertion Decryption Certificate in SSO settings

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: What errors are you encountering?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thx for the answer. Just standart screen with text - We can't log you in because of an issue with single sign-on. Contact your Salesforce admin for help. - when I try to login through SSO. (page link xxxx.my.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/saml/SamlError). No records in LoginHistory.

Comment: Can you verify that your assertion is valid using assertion validator in salesforce! This can be accessed via setup

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thx. I think you are right but where I can found SAML Response?

Comment: The other system which is posting should have something to collect the request xml?